# How do I get into XeTeX development?

Tags: xetex, tex-core

The support for OpenType fonts has been a great advancement in terms of usability.  Unfortunately the `microtype` package does not offer font expansion for OpenType fonts in XeTeX.  I dug a little deeper into that topic and found that XeTeX doesn't offer appropriate primitives.  I would really love to contribute those if I knew how.  I cloned the repository of XeTeX from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code/ci/master/tree/source/), but I can't make any sense of the directory structure.  I don't even know where font stuff takes place.

So the questions are: **Where do I start with XeTeX development?  What are valuable resources to understand the source code?  What are the coding standards and how is the code organised?**

Comment: Are you constrained to work with XeTeX, or are you willing to work with LuaTeX?

Comment: Just ask the current developers ;-)

Comment: You are asking about Tex development but seem to be really wanting xetex, the code base and arrangements and languages use differ depending on what project you are interested in. There is no general answer.

Comment: @Mico My aim is to contribute to XeTeX, but I'm also interested in the details of other projects like LuaTeX or pdfTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I believed that XeTeX is a pdfTeX fork, so what applies to pdfTeX should also apply to XeTeX.  I don't think that I can ever contribute to Knuth TeX, though ;)

Comment: No, xetex isn't based on pdftex (that is why it does not generate pdf output)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay then.  I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To the non-expert the `.xdv` step in XeTeX use might be not at all obvious!

Comment: @HenriMenke The SourceForge layout seems pretty standard to me: very much like TeX Live. I suspect you are trying to find http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code/ci/master/tree/source/texk/web2c/xetexdir/xetex.web (_i.e._ the source for XeTeX in WEB format).

Comment: BTW, Hàn Thế Thành (author of PDFTeX, who also wrote the microtypographic support in XeTeX), was working on the remaining features few years ago, you may want to contact him to see where things are.

Comment: Otherwise, I don’t have much an answer to your question than *read the code*, this is how I got into this and I don’t think there are any general documentation answering the questions you are asking. More specific questions might have better chance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please ask the developers on [the XeTeX mailing list](https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/xetex).

Comment: And then, perhaps, link to the discussion here in the comments :)